# Plugin/ Gem to Implement autocomplete functionality in Rails 2.3.x

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, prototypejs, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to implement auto_complete functionality in Rails 2.3.x application which is developed in Ruby 1.8.7. My application uses pure javascript and prototypen js. I am unable to use jQuery-UI which has inbuilt auto-complete functionality. I need rails plugin or any other javascript plugin to implement in my app.

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Your views are rendered in Rails views, or in some another JS framework ?

Comment: @uno_ordinary Using Rails Views

Comment: If you are talking about a autocomplete functionality for editting / updating something, it should work out of the box, by using `form_for @entity`, where @entity - you declare in your controller, whether `Entity.new` or `Entity.find`